# How to simulate bad internet connection on simulator with code

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, internet-connection

I have downloaded Network Link Conditioner but is there a way I can test this with code? Preferably swift

Comment: http://natashatherobot.com/simulate-bad-network-ios-simulator/ is the link where I downloaded NLC if you are wondering

Comment: Are you a tester? I don't understand your rationale.

Comment: I can already simulate internet connection with NLC. I'm asking is there a way to programaticly do this in my application to get better test results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Because you get the internet connection from the device itself. You can't say in your swift-code:

> Hey I'd like to drop every second data-package to simulate a
>   package-lost rate.

The cause of that is, that you can't change the internet-connection from within your app-sandbox. That's why you need to use an app like NLC to simulate the connection.